# how the bugzilla linked to bugzilla database? how the attachment field saved in the database?

Tags: bugzilla

now i am trying to familiar with the bugzilla, is all the bugzilla being the same format? I mean the same UI, screen? Besides, how is the bugzilla data saved in the database? Using which method? Now the most doubt I have is how will the attachment field in bugzilla saved in database, I mean in which format?

Besides, If I want to extract data from the bugzilla with only several useful fields or columns in order to make several dashboards for displaying to different department about the status of the bugs, should I also linked to the same database? Using API or ODBC or JDBC to talk to database? And among the methods, could you briefing me the most significant difference? Thanks very much...